# Print horizontal whitespace with C language

Tags: c

In this part of code I want to insert white space for print:

("tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext" removes the leading whitespace)

lines:

```
        snprintf(buf, buf_length, "     %s %s", end_time, xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) ? xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) : "");     
        tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);
```

code:

```
 int epg_show_nowandnext( tvtime_osd_t* osd, int page, station_mgr_t *stationmgr, xmltv_t *xmltv )
{
    if (!page)
        return 0;
    if ( xmltv ){
        const int buf_length = 255;
        const int max_num_lines = 15;
        const int num_station_per_page = max_num_lines / 3;
        const int num_stations = station_get_num_stations(stationmgr);
        char *old_channel = strdup(xmltv_get_channel(xmltv));
        char buf[buf_length+1];
        int i, count, cur = 0;


    /* List Header */
    snprintf(buf, buf_length, "Now showing and next on (%d/%d):", page, num_stations/num_station_per_page);
    tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, buf);
    tvtime_osd_list_set_hilight(osd, -1);   

    for (i = (page-1) * num_station_per_page, count = 0; (i < num_stations) && (count < num_station_per_page ); i++, count++) {
        const char *xmltv_id = 0;
        if (!(xmltv_id = station_get_xmltv_id( stationmgr, i))) 
            xmltv_id = xmltv_lookup_channel(xmltv, station_get_name( stationmgr, i));
        xmltv_set_channel( xmltv, xmltv_id);
        xmltv_refresh( xmltv );
        /* Channel number + name */
        snprintf(buf, buf_length, "[%s] %s:", station_get_channel(stationmgr,i), station_get_name( stationmgr, i));     
        tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

        if (xmltv_get_title( xmltv )) {
            char start_time[50];
            char end_time[50];
            time_t start_timestamp = xmltv_get_start_time( xmltv );
            time_t end_timestamp = xmltv_get_end_time( xmltv );
            strftime( start_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &start_timestamp ) );
            strftime( end_time, 50, "%H:%M", localtime( &end_timestamp ) );


            /* Highlight if current channel */
            if (station_get_current_id(stationmgr) == i+1)
                tvtime_osd_list_set_hilight(osd, cur-1);    

            /* starttime of current program + Now showing program */
            snprintf(buf, buf_length, "     %s %s", start_time, xmltv_get_title( xmltv ));      
            if (xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv )){
                strncat(buf," (",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
                strncat(buf,xmltv_get_sub_title( xmltv ),buf_length-strlen(buf));
                strncat(buf,")",buf_length-strlen(buf));  
            }
            tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

            /* endtime of current programme + Next program */       
            snprintf(buf, buf_length, "     %s %s", end_time, xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) ? xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) : "");      
            tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);

        } else {
            /* No program information available for this channel */
            tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, "");
            tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, cur++, "");
        }

    }
    tvtime_osd_list_set_lines( osd, cur );
    tvtime_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );

    xmltv_set_channel(xmltv, old_channel);
    free(old_channel);
    xmltv_refresh( xmltv );

    if (cur > 1){
        return page;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} else {
    tvtime_osd_list_set_text( osd, 0, "No program information available" );
    tvtime_osd_list_set_lines( osd, 1 );
    tvtime_osd_show_list( osd, 1, 1 );
    return !page;
    }
}
```

This print in follow form:

```
[05] TV5MONDE:
09:30 La Grange De Meslay Festival:Pavel Haas Quartet
10:00 TV5Monde Le Journal
[06] RAI UNO
```

I want to print this format with horizontal whitespace:

```
[05] TV5MONDE:
    09:30 La Grange De Meslay Festival:Pavel Haas Quartet
    10:00 TV5Monde Le Journal
[06] RAI UNO
```

I put '*' in code

```
/* showing now  + next showing */       
snprintf(buf, buf_length, "*     %s %s", end_time, xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) ? xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) : "");     
tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext( osd, cur++, buf, 1);
```

Output result (ugly for me):

```
[05] TV5MONDE:
*   09:30 La Grange De Meslay Festival:Pavel Haas Quartet
*   10:00 TV5Monde Le Journal
[06] RAI UNO
```

to make a joke, how to make char '*' invisible?

Comment: is it possible that the whitespace is on the line above?

Comment: Please provide a minimal compilable example which shows your problem.

Comment: Yes, is the whitespace on the line above.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the various output modifiers, in particular the field width: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Something like `%10s` should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can add a tab character at the beginning of the line: `'\t'`

Answer (score 1):

`buf` contains the whitespace. Is it possible that `tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext` removes leading whitespace?

---

According to your comment, `tvtime_osd_list_set_multitext` removes the leading whitespace, so that's what causes the problem. To solve it, perhaps you can use another function to print the whitespace, or you can try to "trick" it by printing some kind of invisible ASCII character in the start of the line.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tab escape code: \t. for example:

```
printf("\tHello World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

quite interesting issue. Where are you collecting the output? One possible explanation could be a wrapping of the initial spaces on the terminal/console receiving your output. Some "built-in" IDE console windows do this kind of mistakes (especially in the past).

Anyway, I would replace your statement based on spaces:

```
snprintf(buf, buf_length, "     %s %s", end_time, xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) ? xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) : "");
```

to

```
snprintf(buf, buf_length, "\t%s %s", end_time, xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) ? xmltv_get_next_title( xmltv ) : "");
```

Comment: With your example, the result is the same. I update my post with example if put one char in front. Thanks